# SQL join and update remove duplicates

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I need help in writing an update query to update master table based on matched table to remove duplicates

**Source table:** tblMatch (this match table is designed to compare and choose customers based on latest date in each row)

```
  RowID  CustID MatchID Date    MatchDate   CustName    CustMatchName
    1       1       2    17-Jan  18-Jan     Joe         Joe
    2       1       3    17-Jan  19-Jan     Joe         Joe
    3       1       4    17-Jan  20-Jan     Joe         Joe
    4       5       4    21-Jan  20-Jan     Joe         Joe
    5       6       5    22-Jan  21-Jan     Joe         Joe
    7       50      55   01-Jan  02-Jan     Alice       Alice
```

if we look at each row, custid and matchid relationship is valid because thier name is same. This table design cannot be changed.

Now the challenge i am facing here is all these 5 records are in fact a copy of one single customer. `1->2,1->3,1->4,5->4,6->5` there for `1->5,1->6`(chaining).

So instead of deciding and finalizing from the first row who is having latest date, i would like to do a scan and identify all the relationships if any(in this case either 1 or 2 can have childs in below rows) and finally customer having latest date should be active among all of its matched  ids, rest all should be inactive.

Below is my detsination table. result i am expecting after this select and update process is CustID 6 will remian Active=1 rest all should be updated to Active=0 in tblCustomer below.

**tblCustomer(Destination table)**

```
CustID  CustName    Active
1       Joe         1
2       Joe         1
3       Joe         1
4       Joe         1
5       Joe         1
6       Joe         1
50      Alice       1
55      Alice       1
100     John        1
101     Nancy       1
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why you have different CustID with only one customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...just hacked together...extra fieds in result so you can see the thought train...I should stop this late night stuff...ugh...

**EDIT**: Updated to show how to update your customer table...

```
CREATE TABLE #tblMatch (
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustID] [int] NULL,
    [MatchID] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [MatchDate] [date] NULL,
    [CustName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CustMatchName] [nvarchar](100) NULL)

CREATE TABLE #tblCustomer (
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustID] [int] NULL,
    [CustName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL)

INSERT INTO #tblMatch
    SELECT 1,2,CAST('17-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('18-Jan-2017' AS date),'Joe','Joe'
        UNION
    SELECT 1,3,CAST('17-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('19-Jan-2017' AS date),'Joe','Joe'
        UNION
    SELECT 1,4,CAST('17-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('20-Jan-2017' AS date),'Joe','Joe'
        UNION
    SELECT 5,4,CAST('21-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('20-Jan-2017' AS date),'Joe','Joe'
        UNION
    SELECT 6,5,CAST('22-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('21-Jan-2017' AS date),'Joe','Joe'
        UNION
    SELECT 1,4,CAST('17-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('20-Jan-2017' AS date),'Sam','Sam'
        UNION
    SELECT 5,4,CAST('23-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('25-Jan-2017' AS date),'Sam','Sam'
        UNION
    SELECT 6,5,CAST('22-Jan-2017' AS date),CAST('21-Jan-2017' AS date),'Sam','Sam'

INSERT INTO #tblCustomer
    SELECT 1,'Joe',1
        UNION
    SELECT 2,'Joe',1
        UNION
    SELECT 3,'Joe',1
        UNION
    SELECT 4,'Joe',1
        UNION
    SELECT 5,'Joe',1
        UNION
    SELECT 6,'Joe',1
        UNION
    SELECT 1,'Sam',1
        UNION
    SELECT 4,'Sam',1
        UNION
    SELECT 5,'Sam',1
        UNION
    SELECT 6,'Sam',1

SELECT [CustID],[CustName],[Status] FROM #tblCustomer
ORDER BY [CustName],[CustID]

UPDATE tCust SET
    tCust.[Status] = tt.[Active]
FROM #tblCustomer tCust INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [CustID],[Date],[CustName],(SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN [Date]>=[MatchDate] THEN [Date] ELSE [MatchDate] END) FROM #tblMatch WHERE [CustName] = t.[CustName] OR [CustMatchName] = t.[CustName]) AS [mxDT],
    CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN [Date]>=[MatchDate] THEN [Date] ELSE [MatchDate] END) FROM #tblMatch WHERE [CustName] = t.[CustName] OR [CustMatchName] = t.[CustName]) = [Date] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Active]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT cust.[CustID],cust.[Date],cust.[CustName]
        FROM #tblMatch cust INNER JOIN #tblMatch match
        ON cust.[CustName] = match.[CustMatchName]
            UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT match.[MatchID] AS [CustID],match.[MatchDate] AS [Date],match.[CustMatchName] AS [CustName]
        FROM #tblMatch cust INNER JOIN #tblMatch match
        ON cust.[CustName] = match.[CustMatchName]
        ) t
    ) tt
ON tCust.[CustID] = tt.[CustID]

SELECT [CustID],[CustName],[Status] FROM #tblCustomer
ORDER BY [CustName],[CustID]

DROP TABLE #tblCustomer
DROP TABLE #tblMatch
```

Comment: hi dave, could you please help me to separate out select part and update part. Other than TblCustomer i have to update few more audit tables in actual code,i am planning to add all updates into a while loop. So if we can get tblMatch into a temp table with the logic you have put. And then the update statement can run against the tmp to make active, inactive. I have added few more records in the example provided above. Sometimes there will be only a single row with just custid and matchid. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: update u
set active = 0
from tblCustomer u inner join tblMatch m
on u.custID = case when M.Date < M.MatchDate then M.CustId else M.MatchId end  this is the existing update code, but it is not handling comparison between rows for chaining. so we can get tblmatch re arranged into a temp table  then final update will take care of comparison between columns

Comment: Ims...I updated my answer. I will give the benefit of the doubt...The original solution basically gave what, from what I can discern from your question, the "trail" to get you to the final solution. It got the status settings I believe you needed but the final step, updating the customer table from comparison should be straight-forward. I provided anyways. If I'm barking up the wrong tree, let me know.

Comment: thank you Dave, i was able to modify the existing update using the concept mentioned above

Comment: Hello @Dave , As i mentioned above this query is working perfectly in finding active and in active. Apart from making customer inactive, i would like to update a forieghn key table also(replace child with parent in foreign key tables ,could you please help in the updte statement for a below table based on #tableMatch 

#tbltest
id 
1
2
3
4
5
6
Output- Id 6 should replace all its child
id 
6
6
6
6
6
6

Comment: @Ims, I don't have any cycles right now but I would look at the inner select statement (...) tt and use that to try to match up the id's and update accordingly...just an initial thought to try...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This will update the field active = 0 and remain the latest CustID active = 1 for every Customer name.

```
Create Procedure proc_update_duplicate as 
begin
)
DECLARE @custid nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @custname nvarchar(50)


 DECLARE Customer_cursor CURSOR FOR  select CustID,CustName from
(select max(CustID) as CustID,CustName as CustName from tblCustomer group by CustName) as a

 OPEN Customer_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_cursor INTO @custid, @custname
  IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0   
        PRINT '         <<None>>'       

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  

       update tblCustomer set active = 0 where CustID != @custid and custName = @CustName


       FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_cursor INTO @custid,@CustName
   END  
   CLOSE Customer_cursor  
    DEALLOCATE Customer_cursor  
END
```

**To Run :** 
exec proc_update_duplicate

Comment: hi reds, we have to compare date for each customer between columns and across rows if the name is matching, i am going to try this to see i can in adddate matching.thx

Comment: Could you show your sample data and a sample result here?

Comment: thank you Reds. Dave has helped me on this. Sample data i have shown above, dave added few more records to simplify.